# Trigger a function at particular time everyday in javascript

Tags: node.js, reactjs, mongodb, express

I'm creating a birthday app where I want to trigger a function at a particular time Eg. At 6 AM. But I'm not getting any idea of how to implement that. Please give a suggestion. Using react as frontend and express as backend and database I use MongoDB. Also, any code reference will help .Thank you in advance.

Comment: On the back-end side, you can run your cron-job and handle that stuff.

Answer (score 1):

A solution can be using a job scheduler such as crontab on Linux machine. If its Windows, cron is called scheduled tasks and It's in the Control Panel. It allows to trigger periodically perform a task.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: @msanli224 Thank you. I think maybe I need to use this. But I wonder that is there anyway to run job scheduler on Front-end?

Answer (score 1):

You can try smth like this, after component rendered setInterval function will check if it is your birthday now or not.Finally, in right moment will invoke some func and disable itself.

```
import React, { useEffect } from 'react';

const BirthDay = () => {

const date = new Date('2022-12-17T03:24:00') //your birthday here
const birthdayFunc = () => {console.log('Birthday!!!')}
const checkBirthday = () => {
    if(new Date() >= date) birthdayFunc()
    else return
}

useEffect(
    () => {
        const id = setInterval(function()
        {
           if(new Date() >= date) 
           {
              birthdayFunc()
              clearInterval(id)
           }
           else return
        }, 1000);
        return () => clearInterval(id);
    },
    []
);

return <div></div>;
};
```